# Writing to a JSON file and uploading to a server

Tags: javascript, json, http

I am pulling a JSON file from a server within my app. When my app deals with this data, I need to write some changes to this JSON file and upload back to the original source.

So if I wanted to edit and write the data in Category in the data below to "Full Stack", how could this be done? I then need to upload to the server to update at their end.

https://gist.githubusercontent.com/planetoftheweb/4069235/raw/0ca9457d10f9ff0be578a699954910d7d6626726/sampledata.json

Comment: Do they provide some kind of api for saving the changes? Or you can upload the file via FTP / SFTP  etc?

Comment: No API, but I could upload to their server via FTP. In which case they perhaps merge the JSON file with their existing data.

Comment: So it's up to them how they merge / replace existing file with the new one. They should give you information about the location where you should upload updated file so they can replace (update) the one you just edited.